# Possible in Rust to perform captures for block expressions?

Tags: rust, expression, shadowing

Simple example of the kind of thing I mean:

```
let x = 10;
if true {
    let x = 20;
}
println!("x is {}", x);
```

This will print `x is 10`, not `x is 20`, and give me an unused variable warning, because the `x` in the if block is different than the `x` outside it. Is there a way I can perform a capture-like operation on the if so that it actually acts on the containing block's `x`?

I'm imagining here that it's desirable to perform shadowing by repeated `let` statements, but the example is more concise if it's just an `int`. In pseudocode, perhaps it would be more like:

```
let data = get_data_from_user();
let data = initial_processing(data);
let data = further_processing(data);
if some_condition {
    let data = conditional_processing(data);
} else {
    let data = fallback_processing(data);
}
```

(Perhaps the answer is that this is code smell, and I should move the `if some_condition` check inside the `conditional_processing` function call.)

So for instance one possible rewrite of the reproducible example:

```
let mut x = 10;
if true {
    x = 20;
}
```

I would consider that to be too divergent from what I'm thinking of doing.

It's possible to write

```
let x = 10;
let mut y = x;
if true {
    y = 20;
}
let x = y;
println!("x is {}", x);
```

And so `x` ends up being a non-mutable variable set to `20`, albeit at the cost of introducing a throwaway intermediary mutable variable `y`. But I'm still curious if it's possible to implement this by letting the `if` block capture and deliberately shadow a variable outside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** (see the original answer below)

You may be interested in

```rust
let data = get_data_from_user();
let data = initial_processing(data);
let data = further_processing(data);
let data = if some_condition {
    conditional_processing(data)
} else {
    fallback_processing(data)
};
```

or if you would like to keep the same value for `else`

```rust
let x = 10;
let x = if true {
    20
} else {
    x
}
```

---

**Original answer**

No, it's not possible.

- You can't force a variable to be visible outside the definition block. So `let x = <...>` will not work.
- You can't change value of immutable variable. So `x = <...>` will not work.
- There is no other way to assign a value to a variable.

Comment: Though you may add that the usual solution would be to call each variable differently ( maybe even a little more descriptive then `data`) or make the variable mutable. Returning the final value from a block to an immutable var may also be an option.

Comment: @L.Riemer, thanks for the comment. Returning a value from a block is the brilliant idea. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by rebinding the same variable.

```rust
// first step, prepare x as mutable
let mut x = 10;
if true {
    x = 20;
}
let x = x; // new binding for x
// from now on, x is immutable
```

A more common (or readable) way to express the same idea:

```rust
let x = {
    // prepare a mutable x just inside this block
    let mut x = 10;
    if true {
       x = 20;
    }
    x // the result of this whole block
};
// in this scope, x is immutable
```

These two constructions have in common the fact that you start
with a mutable binding to initialise the value in multiple
steps, then when it's done, you switch to an immutable binding
of the same value, in order to prevent from accidentally
mutating it.